# Getting the whole word (link) from a phrase, when I know some of it

Tags: string, delphi, substring, text-parsing

Lets say I have a String: `Go to this page: http://mysite.com/?page=1` , and I have a string `page`. I would like to create a function like so:

```
MyBoolean := IsLink('Go to this page: http://mysite.com/?page=1','page',sLink); 
// sLink is a Var, so it would return http://mysite.com/?page=1
```

Basically it is supposed to check if the word "page" is part of a link or not.

However I just can't figure it out. Any tips?

Comment: Does the string always contain the first occurance of "page"? Or in other words: is the format of string always _Go to this page: link_ ?

Comment: @NGLN - No, not always, it can be any phrase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like

```
function GetLinkContaining(const Str, SubStr: string; out URL: string): boolean;
const
  ValidURLSpecialChars = ['.', ':', '/', '?', '=', '&', '%'];
  Prefixes: array[0..4] of string = ('http://', 'https://', 'ftp://', 'mailto:',
    'www.');

  function IsValidURLChar(const Char: char): boolean;
  begin
    result := IsLetterOrDigit(Char) or (Char in ValidURLSpecialChars);
  end;

var
  SubStrPos: integer;
  Start, &End: integer;
  i: Integer;
  URLBegin: integer;
begin
  result := false;

  URLBegin := 0;
  for i := low(Prefixes) to High(Prefixes) do
  begin
    URLBegin := Pos(Prefixes[i], Str);
    if URLBegin > 0 then
      break;
  end;
  if URLBegin = 0 then Exit(false);

  SubStrPos := PosEx(SubStr, Str, URLBegin);
  if SubStrPos = 0 then Exit(false);

  Start := SubStrPos;
  for i := SubStrPos - 1 downto 1 do
    if IsValidURLChar(Str[i]) then
      dec(Start)
    else
      break;
  &End := SubStrPos + length(SubStr);
  for i := SubStrPos + length(SubStr) to length(Str) do
    if IsValidURLChar(Str[i]) then
      inc(&End)
    else
      break;
  URL := Copy(Str, Start, &End - Start);
  result := true;
end;
```

To test it:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
begin
  if GetLinkContaining('Go to this page: http://mysite.com/?page=1 (right now!)',
    'page', s) then
    ShowMessage(s);
  if GetLinkContaining('This is my favourite site (www.bbc.co.uk).', 'bbc', s) then
    ShowMessage(s);        
end;
```

Comment: Perfect! How in the world did you know that? Thats amazing!

Comment: just because you can use `&End` as an indentifier doesn't mean it's a good thing to do.

Comment: @David: Don't be such a square! ;)

Comment: @Andreas - would it be possible to make this function case insensitive?

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, that would be very easy. Replace `Pos(Prefixes[i], Str);` with `Pos(AnsiLowerCase(Prefixes[i]), AnsiLowerCase(Str));` and `PosEx(SubStr, Str, URLBegin)` with `PosEx(AnsiLowerCase(SubStr), AnsiLowerCase(Str), URLBegin)`.

Comment: @Andreas: Wouldn't you just love to see some case and locale insensitive Pos functions added to the RTL like there are for comparing texts (CompareText and AnsiCompareText)? It would save all these calls to (Ansi)LowerCase.

Comment: @Marjan: Yes, that is something I have missed for a very long time.

Answer (score 3):

To check if 'page' is part of a string you can use the function Pos.

function Pos(Str, Source : string): integer;

Pos returns an integer specifying the position of the first occurrence of one string within another.

Pos looks for the first complete occurence of Str in Source. If it finds one, it returns the character position in Source of the first character in Str as an integer value, otherwise it returns 0. Pos is case sensitive. So mybe you have to deal with upper- and lowe-case situations.

To extracrt the URL is (maybe) not so easy, you have to define more conditions. If the URL is always at the end of your string, you can copy everything from the http on (also use Pos and Copy!)

Answer (score 2):

Among the more powerful string matching algorithms there are [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). They allow for very complex matches without writing much code, although mastering them may require a little time. Latest versions of Delphi have already regular expression libraries, but you can find some for earlier versions as well.